# Express app as argument of http.createServer

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, typescript, typescript-typings

When I want to use express.Application as argument of http.createServer I have this error:

`error TS2345: Argument of type 'Application' is not assignable to parameter of type '(request: IncomingMessage, response: ServerResponse) => void'.`

My code:

```
import * as express from "express"
let app: express.Application = express();
...
import * as http from "http"
let httpServer = http.createServer(app);
httpServer.listen(process.env.HTTP_PORT, (): void => {
    console.log(`HTTP Listen on ${process.env.HTTP_PORT}`)
});
```

typings.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "registry:npm/body-parser#1.15.2+20160815132839",
    "express": "registry:npm/express#4.14.0+20160911114220"
  },
  "globalDependencies": {
    "dotenv": "registry:dt/dotenv#2.0.0+20160327131627",
    "errorhandler": "registry:dt/errorhandler#0.0.0+20160316155526",
    "express-serve-static-core": "registry:dt/express-serve-static-core#4.0.0+20160914120416",
    "method-override": "registry:dt/method-override#0.0.0+20160317120654",
    "morgan": "registry:dt/morgan#1.7.0+20160524142355",
    "node": "registry:dt/node#6.0.0+20160921192128"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it. 
Just need to update typings. My current typings.json file:

```
{
  "globalDependencies": {
    "dotenv": "registry:dt/dotenv#2.0.0+20160327131627",
    "errorhandler": "registry:dt/errorhandler#0.0.0+20160316155526",
    "express": "registry:dt/express#4.0.0+20160708185218",
    "express-serve-static-core": "registry:dt/express-serve-static-core#4.0.0+20160916114806",
    "method-override": "registry:dt/method-override#0.0.0+20160317120654",
    "morgan": "registry:dt/morgan#1.7.0+20160524142355",
    "node": "registry:dt/node#6.0.0+20160921192128",
    "serve-favicon": "registry:dt/serve-favicon#0.0.0+20160316155526"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "registry:npm/body-parser#1.15.2+20160815132839",
    "serve-static": "registry:npm/serve-static#1.11.1+20160810053450"
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like the difference in your typings is that you downgraded the Express version. Is that right?

It would be helpful if you provided more info on what was changed, and why.